# Discord.js getting the server owner user tag returns null

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot send an embed when the bot joins a server the embed is supposed to contain the server owner's name but it returns null and doesn't work giving me error TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null

```
guild.owner.user.username
```

the full code

```js
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {        
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${guild.owner.user.username}\nMembers: ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`794483893977088002`).send(EmbedJoin)
});
```

EDIT: i found a solution that worked for me

```js
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
    let owner = client.users.cache.get(guild.ownerID)
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${owner.username}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`758356170926325790`).send(EmbedJoin)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## The user is not always cached.

You can cache it like this: `await client.users.fetch(GUILD.ownerID);`

So, a fixed copy of your code:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {        
    await guild.owner.fetch();
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setDescription(`Guild owner: ${guild.owner.user.username}\nMembers: ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`794483893977088002`).send(EmbedJoin)
});
```

Comment: it still gives me the same error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null"

Comment: Please log guild.owner for me

Comment: abit late ik but it gets error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of null"

Answer (score 0):

For me I was able to get the owner's ID using:

```js
// Instantiate guildID
let guildID;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    guildID = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD ID HERE').ownerID;
});
```

The way I set it up was I instantiated `guildID` as a global var at the top with no value. Then during my `client.on('ready')` function I set the var to be the owners ID. From there you should be able to use that ID to grab the owner's username for your embeds. Let me know if you have any issues with this!

*Edit:*
Forgot to mention. Obviously your functionality is a little different as you want to get the ID when your bot joins a server. However, you should be able to use the same logic and just alter it to fit your needs.

Comment: They don't want the ID, they want the username.

Comment: @LoganDevine you get the user's username from the ID. You get a whole bunch of information about the user but you need that ID to be able to get the username.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the guild `ownerId` from guild. I find in `guild.ownerId`. This will console the user data.

```js
guild.members.fetch(ownerId)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.user)      
    })
```